# Libreoffice Java API failing to export PDF

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I have Java code that exports ODT file to PDF. This is working fine in Windows and MacOS but failing in Linux Mint 19.3. LibreOffice version 6.4.4.2. I can reproduce the same error using the  [DocumentConverter](https://api.libreoffice.org/examples/java/DocumentHandling/DocumentConverter.java) sample class. So I don't think I am doing something wrong in my code. The error is when `storeAsURL()` method is called. Here is the stack trace from `DocumentConverter.java`.

```
com.sun.star.task.ErrorCodeIOException: SfxBaseModel::impl_store <file:////home/leopold/Example.pdf> failed: 0x81a(Error Area:Io Class:Parameter Code:26)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.Job.remoteUnoRequestRaisedException(Job.java:158)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.Job.execute(Job.java:122)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.enter(JobQueue.java:312)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JobQueue.enter(JobQueue.java:281)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.environments.remote.JavaThreadPool.enter(JavaThreadPool.java:81)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.java_remote_bridge.sendRequest(java_remote_bridge.java:619)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.ProxyFactory$Handler.request(ProxyFactory.java:145)
    at com.sun.star.lib.uno.bridges.java_remote.ProxyFactory$Handler.invoke(ProxyFactory.java:129)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.storeAsURL(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.oo.DocumentConverter.traverse(DocumentConverter.java:139)
    at com.example.oo.DocumentConverter.main(DocumentConverter.java:218)
```

I am, however, able to successfully convert to PDF directly using `soffice`:

```
/opt/libreoffice6.4/program/soffice --nologo --invisible --headless \
  --convert-to pdf Example.odt
```

Is there any way I can generate more information about why this error is happening?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that api, but `file:////` that four slashes doesn't look right

Comment: Having three slashes ``file:///home/...`` didn't change anything. Same error.